# How can I concatenate Rolling Regression Results | Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I'm having trouble creating a data frame to store my regression results. For each ticker, it calculates the coefficient(Beta) and its standard error with its respected window.

The new problem that I'm having is that the rows are repeating themselves to calculate each value per column resulting in NaN values. How can I correct the concat?

###### Here is the code

```
def rolling_regression_stats():
    tickers = df[['FDX', 'BRK', 'MSFT', 'NVDA', 'INTC', 'AMD', 'JPM', 'T', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GS']]
    rolling_window = df
    iterable = zip(range(1110), range(52,1162))

    total_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for y, x in iterable:
        for t in tickers:
            model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data= rolling_window.iloc[y:x]).fit()
            beta_coef = model.params['SP50']
            std_error = model.bse['SP50']

            window_range = (f'{y}-{x}')
            
            results = pd.DataFrame({
                "Window":window_range,
                f"{t} Beta":beta_coef,
                f"{t}Beta STD": std_error,
                
            },index=[0])
            total_df = pd.concat([total_df,results], axis=0)
    print(total_df)    
rolling_regression_stats()
```

###### Here is the example of the dataframe I'm trying to create

[image: Example of dataframe]

Here is the current output. But it seems that the calculations are skipping rows for each column resulting in Nan Values.

```
          Window  FDX Beta  FDXBeta STD  BRK Beta  BRKBeta STD  MSFT Beta  MSFTBeta STD  NVDA Beta  ...    T Beta  TBeta STD   AAPL Beta  AAPLBeta STD  AMZN Beta  AMZNBeta STD   GS Beta  GSBeta STD
0           0-52 -0.288299     0.346499       NaN          NaN        NaN           NaN        NaN  ...       NaN        NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
1           0-52       NaN          NaN -0.396694     0.366258        NaN           NaN        NaN  ...       NaN        NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
2           0-52       NaN          NaN       NaN          NaN   1.214212      0.527404        NaN  ...       NaN        NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
3           0-52       NaN          NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN           NaN   7.324437  ...       NaN        NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
4           0-52       NaN          NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN           NaN        NaN  ...       NaN        NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
...          ...       ...          ...       ...          ...        ...           ...        ...  ...       ...        ...         ...           ...        ...           ...       ...         ...
12205  1109-1161       NaN          NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN           NaN        NaN  ...       NaN        NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
12206  1109-1161       NaN          NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN           NaN        NaN  ... -0.294726   0.043549         NaN           NaN        NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
12207  1109-1161       NaN          NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN           NaN        NaN  ...       NaN        NaN  108.959035     12.653105        NaN           NaN       NaN         NaN
12208  1109-1161       NaN          NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN           NaN        NaN  ...       NaN        NaN         NaN           NaN   5.257065      2.785473       NaN         NaN
12209  1109-1161       NaN          NaN       NaN          NaN        NaN           NaN        NaN  ...       NaN        NaN         NaN           NaN        NaN           NaN  1.325418    0.244893
```

Here is the code that fixed it!

```
def rolling_regression_stats():
    tickers = df[['FDX', 'BRK', 'MSFT', 'NVDA', 'INTC', 'AMD', 'JPM', 'T', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'GS']]
    rolling_window = df
    iterable = zip(range(1110), range(52,1162))

    total_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for y, x in iterable:
        yx_df = pd.DataFrame({'window': [f'{y}-{x}']})

        for t in tickers:
            model = smf.ols(f'{t} ~ SP50', data= rolling_window.iloc[y:x]).fit()
            beta_coef = model.params['SP50']
            std_error = model.bse['SP50']

            # window_range = (f'{y}-{x}')
            
            res = pd.DataFrame({f'{t} Beta': beta_coef, f'{t} STDERR': std_error},index=[0])
           
            yx_df = pd.concat([yx_df, res], axis=1)

        total_df = pd.concat([total_df, yx_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print(total_df)
rolling_regression_stats()
```

Comment: You'll just have to revise your loops and concatenation. In your expected result, you have columns for multiple tickers for the same window, so those results need to be concatenated with `axis=1` (column-wise) at the end of each iteration over window values. Then you can concatenate dataframes for different windows together with `axis=0` (row-wise).

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of how I could do this? I'm having a hard time understanding how to implement that @AlexK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using the logic outlined in my comment above. You can see one dataframe (`yx_df`) is initialized for every new `y, x` values, then new columns are concatenated to it for different ticker values with `yx_df = pd.concat([yx_df, res], axis = 1)`, and finally a full row is concatenated to the `total_df` after the loop over all tickers is done with `total_df = pd.concat([total_df, yx_df], axis = 0, ignore_index=True)`.

*Edit*: Added `window` column to the initialization of the `yx_df` dataframe.  That column only needs to have its value assigned once when new `y, x` values are obtained.

```
def rolling_reg():
    tickers = ['FDX', 'BRK']
    iterable = zip(range(5), range(50, 55))

    total_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for y, x in iterable:
        yx_df = pd.DataFrame({'window': [f'{y}-{x}']})

        for t in tickers:
            res = pd.DataFrame(
                {t: np.random.randint(0, 10), f"{t}_2": np.random.randn(1)}
            )
            yx_df = pd.concat([yx_df, res], axis = 1)

        total_df = pd.concat([total_df, yx_df], axis = 0, ignore_index=True)

    return total_df

rolling_reg()

#   window  FDX     FDX_2   BRK      BRK_2
# 0   0-50    7  0.232365     6  -1.491573
# 1   1-51    9  0.302536     1   0.871351
# 2   2-52    6  0.233803     9  -1.306058
# 3   3-53    7 -0.203941     8   0.454480
# 4   4-54    7 -0.618590     7   0.810528
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this:

```
# create a storage df; store this outside of your loop
total_df = pd.DataFrame()

# create your dataframe with results for one regression in the loop
results = pd.DataFrame({
                "Window":window_range,
                f"{t} Beta":beta_coef,
                f"{t}Beta STD": std_error,                
            },index=[0])

# concat the result in the loop like so
total_df = pd.concat([total_df, results], axis=0)
```

Comment: It somewhat worked where all of the columns are correct, but for some reason, I'm getting almost all NaN values, and rows are skipping to the next column. I'll show you an example of the output. @John Stud